# Django multiple admin sites with different templates

Tags: python, django

In the Django docs there is a section detailing how to create multiple admin sites.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#multiple-admin-sites-in-the-same-urlconf

Does anyone know if it is possible to have different templates for each site? So for example I would like to create a customer facing admin site with their branding and another admin site with the standard django templates.

Comment: Yes, You can.


If you look at the [**`AdminSite`** -- (Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-attributes) attributes, there are plenty of attributes and methods that can be used for customization.

Comment: Thanks I did see this however it seems to only be some templates, login, logout, index, app_index and password change. I'm not sure how you would do it for individual apps and models.

Comment: You can also change corresponding templates in ModelAdmin too.

Comment: Ok thank you that makes sense. I would create two ModelAdmin objects and register them on different admin sites.