# How to have multiple Django adminsites with different themes

Tags: django, django-admin, themes, adminlte

I've exactly [the same question](https://www.solveforum.com/forums/threads/solved-how-to-have-multiple-django-adminsites-with-different-themes.506665/) so I took his text and adapted it because he didn't had any answer. I hope I'll have more luck than him.

I have setup a Django project to use both the default admin site and then I have created a separate adminsite. I did this by subclassing admin.AdminSite and registering models with this other admin and it works exactly as intended.

However, I want to use a template such as AdminLTE or Jazzmin with this other admin while sticking with the standard admin theme for the default admin site. I do not know how to do this or if it is even possible.

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420990/django-admin-using-different-templates-for-two-admin-site), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384045/multiple-admin-site-with-different-base-site-html), which is related to the previous one, and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499548/django-multiple-admin-sites-with-different-templates) but they seem to deal with just some html files and not a whole template like AdminLTE. I tried to use the `index_template` attribute and the `index.html` of AdminLTE but it doesn't display my models but the preview of AdminLTE.

Maybe one solution should be to create another project, associate it with the db of my main project and add the lines in `settings.py` as described [there](https://pypi.org/project/django-adminlte-3/) but it's not seem to be a pretty solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can rum multiples admin by changing the port as Django Documentation says
via that command

python3 manage.py runserver 8001 -->this number for example you ca chang it

Comment: It enables us to run the server (not only the admin site) at another port but it doesn't explain how you can use different themes with different admin sites.

Comment: each theme with admin must have a deffrient port